# Grabbing number from text where meets specific critera

Tags: sql-server, string, pattern-matching, sql-like

Ok I have a bunch of data all of which contains a code in the text but it is not all correctly formatted for example:

> Well at Wallgreens Regular Strength Antacid Liquid (Alumina Magnesia Simethicone Antacid & Anti Gas) Mint a)12 oz bottle (NDC 0363-0073-02) b) 26 oz bottle (NDC 0363-0073-26) Distributed by Walgreens CO 200 Wilmot Rd Deerfield IL 60015
>
> IDPN (Intradialytic Parenteral Nutrition - dialysate solution with added amino acids) a) 490mL bag b) 500mL bag and c) 590mL bag Pentec Health Inc 4 Creek Parkway Suite A Boothwyn PA  19061-3132
>
> Aminosyn-PF (amino acids) 7% Sulfite-Free 500 mL Bags Rx Only Hospira Inc Lake Forest IL 60045 NDC: 0409-4178-03 Barcode (01) 0 030409 417803 5

I am only interested in the 8-9 digits formatted like so:

xxxx-xxxx or xxxxx-xxxx

I have currently selected these entries by using:

```
WHERE [Product Description] LIKE '%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%' OR [Product Description] LIKE  '%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
```

but I would like output the string it has matched with the like not the whole Product Description only the code it finds for example:

> 0363-0073
>
> 19061-3132
>
> 0409-4178

Comment: I don't actually see any matches in the sample text you showed us.  Is this an accident?

Comment: 0363-0073-02 is the match of 0363-0073 I am not interested in the trailing 3 characters only first 8/9

Comment: Do you want to extract multiple values from the same text?

Comment: Maybe I am unsure as of yet there are 5000 results to analyse so quite possibly a couple may have multiple codes, so selecting multiple values may well help me a bit further along in this task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a slightly different method, which doesn't use the `UNION ALL`:

```
WITH VTE AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES ('Well at Wallgreens Regular Strength Antacid Liquid (Alumina Magnesia Simethicone Antacid & Anti Gas) Mint a)12 oz bottle (NDC 0363-0073-02) b) 26 oz bottle (NDC 0363-0073-26) Distributed by Walgreens CO 200 Wilmot Rd Deerfield IL 60015'),
                 ('IDPN (Intradialytic Parenteral Nutrition - dialysate solution with added amino acids) a) 490mL bag b) 500mL bag and c) 590mL bag Pentec Health Inc 4 Creek Parkway Suite A Boothwyn PA 19061-3132'),
                 ('Aminosyn-PF (amino acids) 7% Sulfite-Free 500 mL Bags Rx Only Hospira Inc Lake Forest IL 60045 NDC: 0409-4178-03 Barcode (01) 0 030409 417803 5')) V(S))
SELECT V.S,
       CASE WHEN PI1.C > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(V.S,PI1.C, 10)
            WHEN PI2.C > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(V.S,PI2.C, 9)
            ELSE NULL
       END AS N
FROM VTE V
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',V.S))) PI1(C)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',V.S))) PI2(C);
```

The reason for the 2 `PATINDEX`'s is because the values `12345-6789` would fulfil the pattern `'%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'`. Thus the check for the 10 character format is completed first, and then the 9 character. The `CASE` expression also avoids an error if neither pattern is found, as if both `PI1.C` and `PI2.C` return `0` (meaning the pattern wasn't found) then *`NULL`* is returned.

Answer (score 3):

For single value you could use `PATINDEX`:

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(ProductDescription
              ,PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
                        ,ProductDescription),
             10), *
FROM t
WHERE 
 [ProductDescription] LIKE '%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%';
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9acbba02215169bdf6d01fca0774034e)**

Comment: I'm not sure this will work in the instances where there are only 4 digits in front of the hyphen

Comment: @TabAlleman It is partial solution (to show how to use `PATINDEX`) if it has to handle second case you could use `UNION ALL` or condtional logic

Answer (score 0):

You can get the first instance of either code using this (based on the answer by lad2025):

```
declare @t table (v varchar(8000))

insert @t(v) values ('Well at Wallgreens Regular Strength Antacid Liquid (Alumina Magnesia Simethicone Antacid & Anti Gas) Mint a)12 oz bottle (NDC 0363-0073-02) b) 26 oz bottle (NDC 0363-0073-26) Distributed by Walgreens CO 200 Wilmot Rd Deerfield IL 60015'),
('IDPN (Intradialytic Parenteral Nutrition - dialysate solution with added amino acids) a) 490mL bag b) 500mL bag and c) 590mL bag Pentec Health Inc 4 Creek Parkway Suite A Boothwyn PA 19061-3132'),
('Aminosyn-PF (amino acids) 7% Sulfite-Free 500 mL Bags Rx Only Hospira Inc Lake Forest IL 60045 NDC: 0409-4178-03 Barcode (01) 0 030409 417803 5')

SELECT  *
FROM @T

select  substring(v, patindex('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', v), 10)
from    @t
where   v like '%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
union all
select  substring(v, patindex('%[^0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', v), 9)
from    @t
where   v like '%[^0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
```